# Reading JSON data into a webpage/html form from Google Maps Distance API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-directory-api, google-distancematrix-api

I'm very new to Google Maps Distance API.
I'm trying to create a form that calculates the distance between two points using long and lat.

```
<a href="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=53.487362,-2.227197&destinations=51.516595,-0.129279&key=API_KEY">
click here for distance
</a>
```

Clicking the link gives me a results page in JSON format.

[image: l]

How I do read the "distance:text" (209 mi) data and put the value into a `<div>` or `<input>` on the same page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to get and display this data on the client-side, so you should use JavaScript to call the [client-side](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) Distance Matrix service. Not the web service (which is called server-side). E.g.:

HTML

```
<button id="distance-btn" onClick="getDistance()">
  Click here for distance
</button>
<div id="distance"></div>
```

JS

```
function getDistance() {
  const origin = '53.487362,-2.227197';
  const destination = '51.516595,-0.129279';

  var distanceService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  distanceService.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: [origin],
    destinations: [destination],
    travelMode: 'DRIVING',
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status !== 'OK') {
      alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
      const distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text
      document.getElementById('distance').innerText = distance;
    }
  });
}
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bxcto8g5/).

Having said that, if you only want to compute the distance between 1 origin and 1 destination then you're better off using the [Directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) instead. Check out this other [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d24nxkc0/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: Glad to hear & happy to help :)